# github auto authentication with personal access tokens doesn't work

Tags: git, github, github-cli, personal-access-token

I have followed the explanation [here](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/caching-your-github-credentials-in-git) for setting up auto authentication of github on my CLI (on Linux, Ubuntu). In particular, I executed the command given [here](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_auth_login):

`gh auth login`

And then I answered Github.com, yes, HTTPS, and my authentication token to the prompts.

This seems to work: It states "`Configured git protocol`" and "`Logged in as ...`".

However, when I then write `git clone <myrepo>`, it asks me again for my username and password.

What am I doing wrong? My understanding was that the `gh aut login` command is supposed to prevent me from having to type the login data each time.

Comment: @dan1st, I understand that, but the site I linked to states "GitHub CLI will automatically store your Git credentials for you when you choose HTTPS as your preferred protocol for Git operations". Therefore I am assuming that gh is doing some configuration of git behind the scenes, at least if it's working properly. If not, what should I do to log in?

Comment: @dan1st, also note that the title of that page is ""Caching your GitHub credentials in Git.", and the motivation is: "Instead of manually entering your PAT for every HTTPS Git operation, you can cache your PAT with a Git client."

Answer (score 14):

found in the [Github CLI Docs:](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_auth_setup-git)

after you run `gh auth login` then run this command

```
gh auth setup-git
```

Comment: This worked. What the hell Github

Answer (score 8):

In my case it was solved by adding at the end of the file ~/.gitconfig the following:

```
[credential "https://github.com"]
    helper = 
    helper = !/snap/bin/gh auth git-credential
```

Modify /snap/bin/gh with your real path (I've seen others having it in /usr/bin/gh)

Comment: Thank you for sharing this! I don't understand why the GH command doesn't do this, but this helped tremendously.

Comment: worked for me (also installed using snap)

Comment: This works, thanks. what's the purpose of having the first line `helper = ` pointing to nothing?

Comment: Thank you! Been struggling with this for a bit now! Also a note on this: you can run `which gh` to find your path to `gh`. Mine was /var/lib/snapd/snap/bin/gh